# Different Test Settings per project in same solution Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

****Tools:****

1.Visual Studio 2010

2.Visual Studio Unit tests.

****Story:****

We develop a solution that has **several projects**, 
for each project there is a test project. 
Each test project has its **deployment items** that it needs. That's why every test project has its **own test settings**.

**Question:**

I would like to be able to run all the test projects at once to get statistics for all the solution (code coverage, etc..).

Is there any way to do this without merging all test settings into one (this solution maybe problematic)?

**EDITED**

Any other solution to test all the solution will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately project specific test settings are not supported. One solution I often employ is to change the output folder for all projects to a common location. This is also a build performance optimization as dependencies aren't copied multiple times.

This strategy simplifies the deployment strategy as all my test projects write to common folders (ie TestData) and I can add a single deployment item to copy the entire directory for the test run.